I "successfully" killed a turtle that does not exsit in the first place, how to fix this?
I have written the following code to kill a turtle using the service "/kill". When I first run the C++ exeucatable, I successfully killed it. But when I run the code again, I "successfully" killed a turtle that has already been killed.
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "turtlesim/srv/kill.hpp"

class KillClient : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    KillClient(const std::string& turtlename)
        : Node("Kill_client_node"), turtlename_(turtlename)
    {
        kill_client_ = this->create_client<turtlesim::srv::Kill>("/kill");
        
        if (!kill_client_) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_logger(), "Failed to initialize kill client");
            return;
        }

        while(!kill_client_->wait_for_service(std::chrono::seconds(1))){
            RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "Service not available");
        }

        kill(turtlename_);
    }

    void kill(const std::string turtlename)
    {
        auto request = std::make_shared<turtlesim::srv::Kill::Request>();
        request->name = turtlename;
        auto future_result = kill_client_->async_send_request(request);
        rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete(this->get_node_base_interface(), future_result);
        auto response = future_result.get();

        if (response)
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "Killed turtle '%s' successfully", turtlename.c_str());

        }
        else
        {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_logger(), "Failed to kill turtle '%s'", turtlename.c_str());
        }
    }
    private:
        std::string turtlename_;
        rclcpp::Client<turtlesim::srv::Kill>::SharedPtr kill_client_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    auto node = std::make_shared<KillClient>("turtle");
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}

I got the contradictory messages, one from the terminal that started turtlesim , one from the terminal running my C++ exeutable.
[ERROR] [1712837468.186796731] [turtlesim]: Tried to kill turtle [turtle1], which does not exist.
[INFO] [1712837468.187558395] [Kill_client_node]: Killed turtle 'turtle1' successfully exist

How can I rewrite my code to avoid this situation?
